# JQuery and Javascript conditional image changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, conditional-statements

I have  a button that changes the source of images through jquery. Everything was going well until I tried to change the hover state of the images. Here's the code for one image:

```
<td colspan="2" rowspan="3" align="left" valign="top">
    <a href="url">
        <img src="images/cplus.gif" width="89" height="29" id="cplusa" alt="C++" onmouseover="mouseOverImage()" onmouseout="mouseOutImage()" />
    </a>
</td>
```

Here is the code for the button:

```
<td colspan="3" align="left" valign="top">
    <img id="softbutton" src="images/softbuttonpng" width="132" height="33" alt="">
```

This is the jquery code when the button that changes image src is clicked:

```
$('#softbutton').click(function() {
    $(this).attr("src","images/softbuttona.png");
    $("#cplusa").fadeTo(1000,0.30, function() {
        $("#cplusa").attr("src","images/cplusb.png");
    }).fadeTo(500,1);
)};
```

And here is the problem - The hover operators:

```
function mouseOverImage() { 
    document.getElementById("cplusa").src = "images/cplushover.png";
}
function mouseOutImage() { 
    if (document.getElementById("softbutton").src == "images/softbuttona.png")
        document.getElementById("cplusa").src = "cplusb.png";
    else {
        document.getElemebtById("cplusa").src="cplus";
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is to restore the image back to its default state (which depends on the button because it changes the image's src when clicked). The furthest I have gone is to restore the button back to its first state (as if the button was not clicked), but I can never restore it back to its second state (when the button is clicked). With the javascript code I posted here,  the image simply gets stuck into hover state after mouseover.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?  Also, if you're using jQuery already, you can make your life much easier by changing `document.getElementById("cplusa").src;` to `$("#cplusa").attr("src");` (to get) and `$("#cplusa").attr("src", "new value");` (to set).

Comment: Also, remember, using IDs is appropriate when there's only one element with that ID.  Is this the case here?

Comment: Thank you! I rewrote the code with jquery values and it worked like magic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you providing the correct `src` attributes to your button in your `mouseOutImage()` function? Also, consider using the jQuery functions to fetch your elements, for simplicity and robustness...perhaps something like:

```
function mouseOutImage() {
    if ($("#softbutton").attr('src') == "images/softbuttona.png")
        $("#cplusa").attr('src', 'images/cplusb.png'); // fixed source...
    else
        $("#cplusa").attr('src', 'images/cplus.gif'); // fixed source...
}
```

I attempted to interpret your image sources based on previous code you supplied, but I hope this helps lead you to the right answer!